# Twitter Bootstrap: howto reload?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Rather new to Twitter Bootstrap, I am now in front of the following issue.

I have a small web site based on some starter example that I found on the official site.
It works fine up to now.

Here I want to set a way to switch between 2 languages.

For that I have set 2 buttons at the top with the following code, that I also got from one of the examples:

```
  <div class="masthead">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="nav_container">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">English</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Japanese</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
  </div>
```

What do I need to change so the site is reloaded when I click the non-active button?

That would be simple to handle in PHP. I would set a variable , get it with $_POST and ….etc ...
But what is the trick with Twitter Bootstrap?

I have the feeling that it must be simple. Though I did not find the solution by searching the net.
And I have to admit I am much less familiar with JavaScript that Twitter Bootstrap seems to use a lot, than with PHP.

I will appreciate any relevant tip. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that you're trying to use Bootstrap as something it's not. Bootstrap is really just an easy way of handling the presentation (prettiness) of your website.

What you're looking for is a method of switching out the actual content (words etc) of the site.

This could potentially be done in Javascript through the use of downloading the content for both Japanese and English at the same time, then switching the content out, but it's nasty and it should not be done.

**The Correct Way**

This is by using a server side language (such as PHP) to set what language the user is viewing the page in, then serving up the relevant text.

A **very** simplified version of this would be thus:

```
<li class="active"><a href="?set_lang=english">English</a></li>
<li><a href="?set_lang=japanese">Japanese</a></li>
```

Then

```
<?php
  session_start();

  //Set the language in a session to ensure that all future requests to this website
  //will default to being in the correct language
  if(isset($_GET["set_lang"])){
    $_SESSION["language"] = $_GET["set_lang"];
  }elseif(!isset($_SESSION["language"]){
    //Default language
    $_SESSION["language"] = "english";
  }

  if($_SESSION["language"]==="english"){
    echo "Hello!";
  }elseif($_SESSION["language"]==="japanese"){
    echo "Konichiwa!";
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact this is what I ended up by doing. Just did not want to be a miss behaved Bootstrap user.